# Elasticsearch mapping issue when one index already existed from before

Tags: elasticsearch

whenever there is one index already present in Elastic search and I try to create another index with following steps.

1) create an empty index called *dsi2*  with *settings* and *analyzer*

```
curl -XPUT 'https://instance:9243/dsi2' -d '{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "analyzer_keyword": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

2) create mapping,

```
curl -XPUT 'https://instance:9243/_mapping/dsi2' -d '{
  "_all": {
    "enabled": true
  },
   "properties": {
    "formTypeId": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "tenantId": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "formDefinitionId": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "instance": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "integer",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
    .....
```

it throws

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "analyzer [analyzer_keyword] not found for field [raw]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "analyzer [analyzer_keyword] not found for field [raw]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

there is no issue in creating mapping for *dsi2*  when *dsi2* is the only index that was created with same steps 1) & 2) above. if there is already one index created to prior to *dsi2*  - though both indices are separate indices - is there any conflict with the mapping?

Comment: In your second query (create mapping), you're missing the index name, the path should be  `/dsi2/_mapping/dsi2` instead of just `/_mapping/dsi2`

Comment: @Val - that did it. thanks a lot.